# Is it possible to concat a dictionary to an empty DataFrame?

Tags: python, dictionary, concatenation

When I run the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'age':{'sam': 1,
                'rye': 3,
                'lori':8,
                'chris':11,
                'sara':3}}
df = pd.DataFrame()
df = pd.concat([df, data])
```

I get this error:

> TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'dict'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid

I'm wondering if this action is possible or if I'm doing something incorrectly.

Comment: Why do you want to concat a dict to an empty dataframe? Why not just convert the dict to a frame: `pd.DataFrame(data)`

Comment: I have a loop which generates about 10 dictionaries and I would like to concat each dictionary to the same dataframe at the end of every iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to make `data` into a `DataFrame` first:

```
>>> df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(data)])
>>> df
       age
chris   11
lori     8
rye      3
sam      1
sara     3
```

You could then concat further dictionaries to `df` in a loop.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize you couldn't perform this action as is.